# What happens with the test error when the sample size of a training set is reduced?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, linear, error

When performing a linear regression of a training set, the test error increases when the sample size of the training set is reduced.

Is it correct that the test error simply decreases when there is more data available and thus the regression can be made more precisely or is there a different underlying reason?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct. If a linear model is a good model for your data, you expect that by adding more data to the training set you will determine its parameters with higher precision, i.e. the mean value will be closer to the 'real' value. Consequently, when you will try to predict on unseen data, the test set, the prediction of the model will be closer to the 'real' values.